# A basic question on closure of a set in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3,\dots$  be subsets of a metric space. I see in some excercise that closure of infinite union of $A_i$s is a superset (proper) of the infinite union of each of $A_i$s closure whereas for finite union it is equal. I don't understand what is finiteness doing here ?

Comment: Consider $A_n = \lbrace \frac1k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}$. $0$ is in the closure of $\bigcup A_n$, but not in the closure of any $A_n$. For finite unions, if for every set $A_k$ you have a neighbourhood $U_k$ of $x$ that doesn't intersect $A_k$, then $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n U_k$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ that doesn't intersect the union. But an infinite intersection of neighbourhoods is in general not a neighbourhood anymore.

Comment: @DanielFischer If $p$ is a limit point of an infinite union of sets implies for any neighbourhood of $p$ there exists a point $q, q \neq p$ such that $q \in $ infinite union which means $q \in A_i$ for some $i$. This implies $p$ is a limit point of some $A_i$. But your example shows that this is not true. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: @Samprity : I am not from a math background, learning these things newly. I guess these things are pretty trivial to you. Can you please explain ?

Comment: @prasenjit For a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, consider the set $I_U$ of indices $i$ such that $U\cap A_i \neq \varnothing$. The set $I_U$ depends on $U$, with $U \subset V \Rightarrow I_U \subset I_V$. With infinitely many sets $A_i$, it can happen that for each $i$ we can find a neighbourhood $U$ with $i \notin I_{U_i}$, but still all $I_V$ are non-empty.

Comment: understood now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finiteness makes a difference because a finite intersection of neighbourhoods of a point $x$ is still a neighbourhood of that point (because finite intersections of open sets are open).

So if you have a finite union of sets $(A_k)_{1\leqslant k \leqslant n}$, and a point $x$ that is not in the closure of any of the $A_k$, then you have neighbourhoods $U_k$ of $x$ with $U_k \cap A_k = \varnothing$. Then $U = \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n U_k$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ with $U \cap \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k = \varnothing$, and hence $x \notin \overline{\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k}$.

If you have infinitely many sets $(A_k)$, and $x \notin \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty \overline{A_k}$, then you still have a neighbourhood $U_k$ of $x$ with $U_k \cap A_k = \varnothing$, but then $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty U_k$ is in general no longer a neighbourhood of $x$, so you cant deduce $x \notin \overline{\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k}$.

A simple example is $A_k = \lbrace \frac1m : 1 \leqslant m \leqslant k\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Each $A_k$ is closed, and none contains $0$, but we have $0 \in \overline{\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k}$.

Comment: proving by contradiction seems to be easy since we need to find some neighbourhood. I am stuck proving in the straight forward way : i.e. if $p$ is a limit point of a finite union then either $p \in A_i$ for some $i$ or $p$ is a limit point of some $A_i$. and why it won't work for infinite union

Comment: That way isn't so straight-forward. Consider the case of a union $A\cup B$ of only two sets. Let $p\in\overline{A\cup B}$. To show that $p\in\overline{A}$ or $p\in\overline{B}$, the simplest method I am aware of is: "If $p\notin\overline{A}$, then $\exists U\in\mathcal{V}(x)$ with $U\cap A=\varnothing$, and hence $\varnothing\neq(V\cap U)\cap(A\cup B)=V\cap(U\cap(A\cup B))=V\cap((U\cap A)\cup(U\cap B))=V\cap(U\cap B)\subset V\cap B$ so $p\in\overline{B}$". For unions of $n$ sets, that would be assuming $p$ isn't in the closure of $n-1$ of the sets, and deducing it's in the closure of the last

Comment: We have $\varnothing \neq (V\cap U) \cap (A\cup B)$ because $V\cap U$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ ($U$ and $V$ both are), and by assumption $p \in \overline{A\cup B}$. Since $U\cap A = \varnothing$, we also have $(V\cap U) \cap A = \varnothing$. So $(V\cap U)\cap(A\cup B)$ contains only points of $B$, none of $A$. Since it's nonempty, it contains some point(s) of $B$. Therefore a fortiori $V\cap B \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: understood now.